# Can't figure out z-index

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

Want my countdown div to be under the header_top div, and I can't figure out why my z-index won't work. Tried using position:relative, but I guess I'm using it wrong.

Could someone please help?

index.php:

```
        <div class="header_top">
                <div class="links">
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/tweet.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/face.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/youtube.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/streg.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/faq.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/message.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/info.png" >
                        </div>
                </div>


        </div>

    <div class="countdown">
    </div>
```

styles.css:

```
.header_top {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    width:1024px;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url(../img/top.png);
}
.links {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:350px;
    height:45px;
}
.link {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin:3px 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.countdown {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background-image:url(../img/count.png);
    width:1024px;
    height:160px;
}
```

Comment: So... why was this tagged `PHP`?

Comment: @AmalMurali coz his file extension is `index.php` XD

Comment: use `position:absolute` on your `countdown`, when using `relative` left,right,top,bottom translate the element from its relative position in the flow, so top:0 and left:0 does not move it at all.

Comment: Removing left and top worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `position: absolute;` to `.countdown` selector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want your `.countdown` div actually positioned in the same place as `.header_top` and *layered* under it? If so, then you need to position the `.header_top` absolutely:

```
.header_top {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute; //here's the only change in your code
    z-index:2;
    width:1024px;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url(../img/top.png);
}
(...)
```

Note that `.header_top` will be positioned relatively to it's closest parent which is positioned `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`. If there is no such, then `.header_top`'s position will be relative to `body`.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is a property of CSS that allows you to set the stack order of specific elements. An element with a greater stack order, will always be in front of one with lower. z-index was introduced in css2 its not inherited and its default value is auto. The javascript syntax for setting the z-index is object.style.zIndex="1". These are some small little tips and knowledge surrounding the z-index property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Change the z-index from -1 to 1 in this little test. You will see how it works properly. You can take from their code and try to fix your issue. Hope this helped.

The issue is in position setting you have. Setting it to relative, means it is relative and partial to other divs in the area. Absolute means you have decided its position and no matter the number of divs set to top: 0 left: 0 with position: absolute.

Comment: he is not actually having a problem with his z-index, he has his z-index styles set properly, his problem is him not using the correct `position` style

Comment: If you read through my entire answer, I explain the difference between his position settings. The z-index explanation is to help him understand how to properly use it.

Answer (score 0):

Position relative is probably not what you are looking for.  Position: Relative positions an element relative to what its position normally would have been.  So in essence, you are just taking where it would have been, and moving it.

Position absolute on the other hand positions in regards to its previous ancestor.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

You also want higher z-index values for elements you want to appear above other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but you could maybe do:

```
<div id="countdown">
<div class="header_top">
                <div class="links">
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/tweet.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/face.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/youtube.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/streg.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/faq.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                        <img src="img/message.png" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">`enter code here`
                        <img src="img/info.png" >
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             <div>
```

This way you could style countdown accordingly and contain the other divs within it.